# ManyToMany and checkBoxListRow

Tags: php, yii

I'm using Yii with Yii-Bootstrap for the widgets. My Models are generated via Gii.
I have a simple database like this

```
video <-> video_tag <-> tag
```

and I want to set the tags of a video using the following widget in the video form:

```
$form->checkBoxListRow($model, 'tags', CHtml::listData(Tag::model()->findAll()));
```

This gives me the following error, when I try to edit a video, that already has tags in video_tag

```
Object of class Tag could not be converted to int
```

The Model seems to be generated correctly

```
'tags' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Tag', 'video_tag(video_id, tag_id)'),
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is there a general problem with many-to-many relations in CHtml, or checkBoxListRow?

Comment: Problem lies in CHtml::listData(Tag::model()->findAll())

Comment: check its usage http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/48/by-example-chtml/#hh4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three problems :

- you should not use `tags` attribute with `checkBoxListRow` since you need an array containing values, not objects.
- you should add 2 missing arguments for [`CHtml::listData()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#listData-detail)
- how do you save corresponding entries in `video_tag` table ?

You should for example (assuming `Tag` class have `id` and `name` attributes) :

**In Video model** :

```
private $_tagsIds;

public function getTagsIds()
{
    if (!isset($this->_tagsIds))
    {
        $this->_tagsIds = array();
        foreach ($this->tags as $tag)
            $this->_tagsIds[] = $tag->id;
    }

    return $this->_tagsIds;
}

public function setTagsIds($tagsIds)
{
    $this->_tagsIds = $tagsIds;
}

protected function afterSave()
{
    // TODO : save entries in video_tag table using $_tagsIds data

    parent::afterSave();
}
```

**And in your view** :

```
$form->checkBoxListRow($model, 'tagsIds', CHtml::listData(Tag::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'name'));
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer! I guess I overestimated what Gii could do for me – Why even use it, if it only detects, yet not "resolves" many-to-manys…  
Your solution works perfectly and more important pointed me to the right direction – Thanks!